# Why is visual studio code printing C# to terminal correctly, but not output?

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-code

I'm new to C#. I installed Visual Studio code along with the NET framework, and when I run my project in the terminal via 'dotnet run', everything works perfectly.

Yet, when I switch over to the output window I see this message -- [image]

Can anyone lead me in the right direction? I've been going at it for 10 hours now - research, reinstalls, and restarts galore - yet nothing seems to help. Again I stress: in the visual studio terminal, the code works fine.

What gives?

Edit: I manually added scriptcs to path, and now the error has change - "You cannot declare namespace in script code"

```
using System;
namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Hello 
    {
        static void Main() 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            // Keep the console window open in debug mode.
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

This is what happens without namespace; still no output.

[image]

Comment: Is the scriptcs folder in your path environment variable?

Comment: I don't even know where the scriptcs would be, or if I even have it. The dotnet stuff is, though. Are they seperate entities?

Comment: you can check it running `where scriptcs` from the cmd prompt. If it's in the path it will tell you where it is. If not, you can install it as described http://scriptcs.net/. After that it should be in your <username>\AppData\Local\scriptcs directory. Check and ddd this directory to the PATH variable if necessary.

Comment: Now it's giving me this error: [Running] scriptcs "c:\Users\Owner\Desktop\C++\myApp\Program.cs"
Copying directory 'bin' to 'scriptcs_bin'...
ERROR: Script compilation failed. [CompilationErrorException] c:\Users\Owner\Desktop\C++\myApp\Program.cs(3,1): error CS7021: You cannot declare namespace in script code

Comment: (Script still works fine with dotnet, isn't a coding error)

Comment: It's complaining about the namespace, so remove it from the Program.cs

Comment: It compiles now, but still no output - just 'Running' and then 'Done'. On the contrary python scripts work fine, and the terminal is still printing on course. (image added above)

Comment: Nevermind. I got it; had to erase everything except:          Console.WriteLine("Hello jhjhjWorld!");
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
    Console.Read();
thanks so much, guys!!!!

Comment: Please DO NOT include your answer inline in the question - instead you should answer the question, and mark yours as the answer.

Comment: My bad. I'll edit.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, I had to get rid of everything aside from:

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");      
Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
Console.ReadKey();
```

I don't know why, but now 'run dotnet' in terminal doesn't work, yet the output does. Regardless, thanks to everyone who helpeD!!!